# Jquery strong password validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sorry to ask but I'm soo new to javascript and Jquery!
I've been struggling to make this piece of code from a plugin I'm using to accept only strong passwords.

It meets the minimum length requirement, matching fields and checks the field is not empty; but I can not get it to incorporate A-Z, a-z, 1-0 etc...Here is my best try that doesn't work

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
function strongpass_submit(url) {   

    jQuery("#strong-error", jQuery("#action")).hide();
    var witherror = false;
    var passval = jQuery("#strong-pw", jQuery("#action")).val();
    var okval = jQuery("#strong-pw-confirm", jQuery("#action")).val();
    if (passVal == '') {
            jQuery("#strong-error", jQuery("#action")).html('Please enter a password.').fadeIn();
            return false;

//THIS IS THE PART I'M HAVING TROUBLE WITH
    } else if (okval.search(/^([A-Z0-9.%+-]+@@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,6})*([,;][\s]*([A-Z0-9.%+-]+@@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,6}))*$/i)) {
        jQuery("#strong-error", jQuery("#action")).html('Password must be strong.').fadeIn();
        return false;
// UNTIL HERE

    } else if (okval.length < 8) {
        jQuery("#strong-error", jQuery("#action")).html('Password must be at least 8 characters.').fadeIn();
        return false;

    } else if (okval == '') {
        jQuery("#strong-error", jQuery("#action")).html('Please re-enter your password.').fadeIn();
        return false;
    } else if (passval != okval ) {
        jQuery("#pass-error", jQuery("#action")).html('Passwords do not match.').fadeIn();
        return false;
    }
    jQuery('#action #maindiv').fadeOut('fast', function(){
        jQuery('#popout').show();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            data: jQuery('#action form').serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                if(data.confirm == 'success'){
                    jQuery('#cboxLoadingGraphic').fadeOut('fast', function(){
                        jQuery('#action #second').fadeIn();
                    });
                }
                else {
                    jQuery('#cboxLoadingGraphic').fadeOut('fast', function(){
                        jQuery('#action #openerror').fadeIn();
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Why did you use the case insensitive flag? It seems your whole regex there is messed up...

Comment: You're right!... Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
   .weak{
   color:red;
   font-size: 17px;
   }
   .good{
   color: #17da17;
   font-size: 17px;
   }
   .strong{
   color: #339333;
   font-size: 17px;
   }
</style>
<form id="password-check">
   <label>Password : </label>
   <input name="pass" id="pass" type="password"/>
   <span id="message"></span>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function()
   {
   $('#pass').keyup(function()
   {
   $('#message').html(checkStrength($('#pass').val()))
   }) 
   function checkStrength(password)
   {
    var useremail="testing@gmail.com";
    var username="testing";
   
    var strength = 0
    if (password.length < 6) { 
        $('#message').removeClass();
        $('#message').addClass('weak');
        return 'Too short!';
    }
    if ((username.indexOf(password) > -1) || (password.indexOf(username)> -1))
    {
        $('#message').removeClass();
        $('#message').addClass('weak');
        return "Password must be different from user name!"; 
    }
    if ((useremail.indexOf(password) > -1) || (password.indexOf(useremail)> -1))
    {
        $('#message').removeClass();
        $('#message').addClass('weak');
        return "Password must be different from user email!"; 
    }
    if (password.length > 7) strength += 1
    if (password.match(/([a-z].*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*[a-z])/))  strength += 1
    if (password.match(/([a-zA-Z])/) && password.match(/([0-9])/))  strength += 1 
    if (password.match(/([!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/))  strength += 1
    if (password.match(/(.*[!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~].*[!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/)) strength += 1
    if (strength < 2 )
    {
        $('#message').removeClass();
        $('#message').addClass('weak');
        return 'Weak!';   
    }
    else if (strength == 2 )
    {
        $('#message').removeClass();
        $('#message').addClass('good');
        return 'Good!';  
    }
    else
    {
        $('#message').removeClass();
        $('#message').addClass('strong');
        return 'Strong!';
    }
   }
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Please make sure to provide some explanations on your code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your regex in these problematic lines is wrong.
In order to validate an input with such requirements you can use this code, with multiple regular expressions:

```js
var okval = "Abcd123!";
var print = (/[A-Z]/.test(okval) && /[0-9]/.test(okval) && /[^A-Za-z0-9]/.test(okval) && okval.length>7);
console.log(print);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot GalAbra... To be honest I don't really know what I'm doing. I tried with your regex and it still skips it like nothing. Also, I wouldn't know how to apply the verification code you provided... I'm sorry, that's the level I'm at. Do you think the "search" method is valid before the regex?... I'm about to give up

Comment: Can you please specify what exactly is a valid password? You have a couple of problems with the `search` method.. The moment I understand the password specifications I'll edit and explain more thoroughly about the implementation as well!

Comment: Hi again GalAbra... The valid password should contain at least 1 capital letter, 1 number, 1 symbol and 8 characters.

Comment: @Josh045 Check this out now, let me know if it works for you

Comment: Thanks @GalAbra... It doesn't seem to work. I feel dumb with this but where should your code exactly go?

Comment: `print` returns a bookean value to validate `okval`